# configuring dependencies intellij idea, maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I've created a maven project, imported my dependencies and checked the libraries which contain the expected files (except for the doc-files which are red).

For some reason (and I'm having this problem in both intellij and eclipse), If I create a class the imports and methods cannot be resolved.

[image: The pom.xml file]

[image: The javaclass]

Comment: Transitive dependencies do not seem to be resolved. Are there errors in the Maven tool window?

Comment: please, add pom.xml and SpellRunner as text

Answer (score 0):

I would build the project on the command line to download the dependencies and then invalidate the caches in Intellij (under File menu) and restart IntelliJ.